# Running a gui app with Powershell without displaying the gui

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to run an app (it does not natively support command line mode) on Windows that require 5 fields of generic data from a user. However, I want to run this app without opening/displaying the gui (a la command line like). Is this something that can be done with Powershell. If so, can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the app and whether it accepts command line arguments. For interacting with GUIs, [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) may be a better bet. [This random Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS-ycdoOyj8) introduces mouse/keystrokes

Comment: [This PowerShell Snapin](http://wasp.codeplex.com) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Launch a scheduled task as System using schtasks

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does not change how an application is executed versus how it is when executed at the command line or a run dialog. If the application can accept input via arguments when run then any of these methods for executing the application will work.

If you are asking if powershell can read from the console host, the appropriate cmdlet would be read-host. So you could read from the user and then run the command with the arguments you desire.

```
$user = read-host "Username:"
& examplecommand.exe $user
```